# C#. Is this a valid conditional statement?

Tags: c#, methods, conditional-statements, execution

I have two methods, `A` and `B`. Only after the success of two the methods I have to insert into a database. So is this a valid conditional Statement in C#?

```
if (A() && B())
{
    //insert into db
}
```

After the execution of method `A` I have to execute `B`. If both are successful I have to do the insert.

Comment: Really.. Yes that's fine, but this is something really, really easy to test in seconds.

Comment: People use SO instead of a debugger these days.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes it is valid. But note that `B` will only execute if `A()` returns true.

Answer (score 2):

This is called [short-circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation)

The conditions will be evaluated in the order of appearance, and only if their testing is still relevant. That is, if A() fails, there is no reason to test B().

Answer (score 0):

As they say B() is not executing if A() returns false.
If you want both functions to be executed I recommend something like:

```
bool resultA = A();
bool resultB = B();
if(resultA && resultB)
{
    //insert into db
}
```

Comment: -1 for using the && operator at all in a situation where you don't want short-circuiting.

Comment: the example is obviously not short-circuiting the functions which is what the example demonstrates

Answer (score 0):

Your question has already been answered by others, but just to clarify as there are a couple of slightly misleading posts on here...

The `&&` operator is short-circuiting

`if (false && Foo()) // Foo() is not run`

The `&` operator is **not** short-circuiting

`if (false & Foo()) // Foo() is run`

Use the latter if your functions have side effects which you want to ensure.

Answer (score -2):

set fa=1 fd=1 inside both function.

Then check

if(fa==fb==1)
{
//do
}

Comment: Seriously dude? That is really ugly code. You even want him to instantiate two global variables instead of using return values for something this trivial?.. sigh! If something goes wrong inside the methods it should be caught by a try catch outside.

Answer (score -7):

It should be

```
if(A()) 
{ 
   if(B())
   {
    //insert into db 
   }
}
```

This will take care that both the functions are getting executed.

Comment: why will this take care about that both functions are executed?? If `A()` fails, then `B()` won't be executed, so it exactly the same as the code in the question.